# jQuery UI Tabs Not Tapable When All on 1 Line with Overflow Auto so it can Scroll Horizontally

Tags: android, html, jquery-ui, css, tabs

I'm having an issue with an AppMobi app: HTML5 and CSS on a WebKit browser concerning horizontally scrollable jQuery UI Tabs.

You can see an example here:
http://keith-wood.name/uiTabs.html#tabs-one-line

If you view that on your Android phone (at least when I do it with my Galaxy S3) you can see them, they scroll back and forth just fine, but none of the tabs are clickable.  I'm having exactly the same issue in my app so it's a fine example.

The problem doesn't occur on my iPhone 5, and it's not a problem on Android if the screen is large enough that they don't need to scroll.

Anyone know of a way to achieve clickable tabs in this situation?  I've added position: relative; on the containing elements, and it works better now, but if it is scrolled all the way to the right, it still doesn't work, but will now work if it's anywhere except all the way to the right. Weird.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set any limitations on the horizontal overflow?

Comment: The ul has a set min-width so that it overflows the screen of a phone when in portrait and is horizontally scrollable, and a width of 100%. It's container is set to overflow auto. When in landscape the min-width is less than the screen width so it centers and works fine.